# Running custom Apache Phoenix SQL query in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

Could someone provide an example using pyspark on how to run a custom Apache Phoenix SQL query and store the result of that query in a RDD or DF. Note: I am looking for a custom query and not an entire table to be read into a RDD.

From Phoenix Documentation, to load an entire table I can use this:

```
table = sqlContext.read \
        .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
        .option("table", "<TABLENAME>") \
        .option("zkUrl", "<hostname>:<port>") \
        .load()
```

I want to know what is the corresponding equivalent for using a custom SQL

```
sqlResult =  sqlContext.read \
             .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
             .option("sql", "select * from <TABLENAME> where <CONDITION>") \
             .option("zkUrl", "<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>") \
             .load()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using Phoenix as a JDBC data source as given below:

```
sql = '(select COL1, COL2 from TABLE where COL3 = 5) as TEMP_TABLE'

df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc')\
       .options(driver="org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver", url='jdbc:phoenix:<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>', dbtable=sql).load()

df.show()
```

However it should be noted that if there are column aliases in the SQL statement then the .show() statement would throw up an exception (It will work if you use .select() to select the columns that are not aliased), this is a possible bug in Phoenix.

Comment: Is this an answer or part of the question?

Comment: Both. It used JDBC to achieve what I wanted to do, but using Phoenix Spark option would be better, hence my attempt at it and the corresponding error message.

Comment: Question should be edited in first post, because this is answer section. stackoverflow is not like normal forums.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use .sql to work with custom queries. Here is syntax

```
dataframe = sqlContext.sql("select * from <table> where <condition>")
dataframe.show()
```

Comment: That would not work because we are not telling Spark to use Phoenix anywhere. This is a link to Phoenix Documentation https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html

Answer (score 0):

To Spark2, I didn't have problem with .show() function, and I did not use .select() function to print all values of DataFrame coming from Phoenix.
So, make sure that your sql query has been inside parentheses, look my example:

```
 val sql = " (SELECT  P.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID, P.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME, C.STATUS as STATUS FROM PERSON P INNER JOIN CLIENT C ON C.CLIENT_ID = P.PERSON_ID) "
          val dft = dfPerson.sparkSession.read.format("jdbc")
            .option("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver")
            .option("url", "jdbc:phoenix:<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>")
            .option("useUnicode", "true")
            .option("continueBatchOnError", "true")
            .option("dbtable", sql)
            .load()
dft.show();
```

It shows me:

```
+---------+--------------------+------+
|PERSON_ID|           LAST_NAME|STATUS|
+---------+--------------------+------+
|     1005|             PerDiem|Active|
|     1008|NAMEEEEEEEEEEEEEE...|Active|
|     1009|           Admission|Active|
|     1010|            Facility|Active|
|     1011|                MeUP|Active|
+---------+--------------------+------+
```